# "Transpose" a multi-map to a list of maps

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Suppose I have a multi-map like this:

```
MiddleName -> null
EmailAddress -> Toni@mymail.com, Mary@hermail.com, Paul@hismail.com
FirstName -> Toni, Mary, Paul
LastName -> Barry, null ,White
Id -> null
```

Note how each "values" entry can be entirely null or contain the same number of values as the one with more entries (which I don't know which is) even if some are null.

I want it to "transpose" it to a list of maps like this:

```
MiddleName -> null
EmailAddress -> Toni@mymail.com
FirstName -> Toni
LastName -> Barry
Id -> null

MiddleName -> null
EmailAddress -> Mary@hermail
FirstName -> John
LastName -> null
Id -> null

MiddleName -> null
EmailAddress -> Paul@hismail.com
FirstName -> Paul
LastName -> White
Id -> null
```

I'm trying to do this with java8 streams, but can do it in the "old" style as well.

Searching stackoverflow I found a similar question [1] and a few more also related [2,3,4] that gave me some ideas but were not fully adaptable.

Now, I did implement my own solution that works as I want, but frankly this is probably the most ugly code I wrote in years...

```
List result = (...)
map.forEach(h -> {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> m = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
    h.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
        String[] ss = e.getValue() == null ? null : e.getValue().toString().split(",");
        if (ss != null) {
            Arrays.asList(ss).stream().forEach(s -> m.add(e.getKey(), s));
        }
    });
    if (m.size() > 0) {
        int x = m.values().stream().max((o1, o2) -> o1.size() - o2.size()).get().size();
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            Map<String, String> n = (Map) h.clone();
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = n.entrySet().iterator();
            while( it.hasNext()){
                Map.Entry<String, String> e = it.next();
                List<String> ss = m.get(e.getKey());
                if(ss!=null) {
                    e.setValue(ss.get(i));
                }
            }
            result.add(n);
        }
    }
});
```

The first pass is just to split the string into a array since originally it's a comma separated string. Then I find the max number of elements in any value, I loop all the values in the entries for that number of times and create the a map for each value with the results. To be frank I wrote this code last Friday and I can't already read it properly...

So, this was at first a simple thing to do and I ended up with this mess, is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

[1] [Java8 streams : Transpose map with values as list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471056/java8-streams-transpose-map-with-values-as-list)

[2] [reversing keys/values - create new instance of HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475663/reversing-keys-values-create-new-instance-of-hashmap)

[3] ["Transpose" a hashmap for key->value to value->key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347570/transpose-a-hashmap-for-key-value-to-value-key)

[4] [Java invert map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146990/java-invert-map)

Answer (score 0):

I would frankly try to avoid being in that situation in the first place, and start using real objects instead of maps (even your desired list of maps should really be a `List<Person>`), but I would do it like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> multiMap = ...;
List<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

// find an entry with a non-null value, and get the size of the
// list
OptionalInt sizeOfLists =
    multiMap.values()
            .stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .mapToInt(List::size)
            .findAny();

// for each index, create a person and put each key and the
// corresponding value at that index in that map
sizeOfLists.ifPresent(size -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int index = i;
        Map<String, String> person = new HashMap<>();
        result.add(person);
        multiMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() != null)
                .forEach(entry -> person.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get(index)));
    }
});
```

Note that your code is not so terrible. But it would be much more readable if you gave meaningful names to your variables instead of `h`, `m`, `e`, `ss`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I can't avoid this situation unfortunately, as this is part of a bigger stream of operations. Your code is quite readable, I can understand it just by looking at it. I'm going to try it, since my actual scenario is a little more complicated than this. And relating to my variables naming you are, of course, right... :) I'll let you know how it goes. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

How about this (if I understood everything correctly):

```
    Multimap<String, String> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    map.put("MiddleName", null);
    map.putAll("EmailAddress", ImmutableList.of("toni@gmail.com", "mary@gmail.com", "paul@gmail.com"));

    // that's the key with the "biggest" collection within the map
    int biggest = map.asMap().entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.reducing(0, entry -> entry.getValue().size(), Integer::max));

    Multimap<String, String> newMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

    // "padding" the collection when required
    map.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> {
        int currentSize = map.get(key).size();
        newMap.putAll(key, map.get(key));
        if (currentSize < biggest) {
            newMap.putAll(key, Collections.nCopies(biggest - currentSize, (String) null));
        }
    });

    System.out.println(newMap); // {MiddleName=[null, null, null], EmailAddress=[toni@gmail.com, mary@gmail.com, paul@gmail.com]}
}
```

Mapping to some Person object is fairly easy from here.